# SQL Advice - selecting based upon column in another table

Tags: c#, sql

I'm having a bit of headache with some SQL I'm trying to write. Basically, there's 2 tables that have the following fields (only relevant ones to SQL displayed):

> Invoices
>
> ```
>  accno (fk, linked to id on accounts)
> ```
>
> Accounts
>
> ```
>  id (pk)
>  allocateduser
> ```

Basically, my SQL needs to return all invoices for which account has their current logged in name as the AllocatedUser, which is stored in a Session. Is this simple to do?

Thanks

Comment: here's a good article on SQL joins:  www.devshed.com/c/a/MySQL/Understanding-SQL-Joins/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look up all accounts for a user with a `where` statement, and link the result to the invoices table with a `join`.  For example:

```
select  *
from    invoices i
join    accounts a
on      i.accno = a.id
where   a.allocateduser = 'YourUser'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use semi-join:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM invoice
 WHERE EXISTS(

SELECT 1 
  FROM accounts 
 WHERE allocateduser = @allocateduser_value
   AND pk = fk)
```

@allocateduser_value is parameter you pass from your session. Beware on case of string, so John is not john ;-)